# Why are the vote counts for comments colored sometimes?

Tags: discussion, comment, voting

Pardon me if this is a silly question, but I have noticed that the little number displaying the number of votes on each comment is sometimes colored. I'm guessing the color is based on the number of votes, but is there a specific rule for this?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97063/whats-the-deal-with-color-coding-of-comment-votes). In the comments to that question is [a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85847) to the code for the coloring of comments.

Later in the comments, it is mentioned that the coloring is dynamic. That means that there are no set cutoffs for what number gets what color.

Comment: I am tempted to run an experiment. Post 255 indexed comments and get each comment to be voted as its index.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd participate! :p

Comment: The experiment has begun, @anorton

Comment: @Daniel: There's not enough people on meta, and it will be very easy to screw around this by voting comments past their indicated index.

Comment: Ideally, such an experiment would consist of 255 comments, all consisting of a single natural number, followed by `${}{}{}$`.  Then, each comment would be voted to the target natural number.  You can't do this with just "normal" comments, because overshooting would be too easy.

Comment: @anorton: Obviously, but it is still easy to screw up by people who want to ruin it for no good reason.

Comment: @asaf True.  I guess it's just not worth it...

Comment: We're going to need an 11th one soon :)